# Why is my static array not cleared by memset?

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32

I want to have a simple float to string converter for an embedded project and would like to not use floating-point `snprintf` as that would really fill my flash, so i wrote a simple conversion function. I don't really care for an exact number of decimals nor negative values. This is just a C++ example, i do not want to use STL nor other C++ specific functions as i'm really constrained in terms of space in the real project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

char msg[100];

typedef uint32_t u32;

char* floatToString(float value)
{
    static char placeholder[100];
    memset(placeholder, '\0', sizeof placeholder);

    auto root = (u32) value;
    auto decimals = (u32) (value * 1000) % 1000;

    snprintf(placeholder, 100, "%lu.%lu", root,
            decimals);

    return placeholder;
}

float weirdVal = 11.35;

int main(){
    snprintf(msg, 100, "%s,%s", floatToString(weirdVal), floatToString(64.876));

    std::cout << msg << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```

When i test the function and call it, i always get the number passed first. My output is:

```
11.350,11.350
```

Comment: `snprintf` to this function `placeholder` address is passed twice, before `snprintf` is called `placeholder` is overwritten. as all the args are evaluated before the function call

Comment: The address returned by the function is the same for both operands in main. Whatever is in that buffer after `floatToString` has been called both times is what you'll see printed. Last one wins.

Comment: Why did you pick C++ if you are constrained in space? `snprintf` is light-weight in comparison with the iostream lib. Also why would your STM32 application return from main(), you want it to execute once then crash, or...?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't really describe the nature of the problem you are having, wanna watch that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a common buffer for the converted value.

And since the order of evaluation *on your system* apparently evaluates the rightmost argument first, you only see the last conversion of 11.35.

You can work around by:

- printing the converted values separately
- use another kind of buffering (dynamic, local to caller, ...)

*Note: You need to format `"%lu.%03lu"` to get correct results for example for 23.007.*